# ejs template not rendering properly

Tags: node.js, passport.js, ejs, passport-local

I am trying to replicate a tutorial on using passport to create user authentication.

whenever i try including the below snippet in **signup.ejs**:

```
<% if (message.length > 0) { %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
<% } %>
```

it throws error and as soon as i remove this from signup.ejs, it renders.

below is my **app.js**(includes all the configurations), **index.js**(routing part), **signup.ejs** 
 and **passport.js**(link to this file is mentioned)

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');    

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://jer:jer@ds061611.mongolab.com:61611/passport1");
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

require('./config/passport')(passport);
app.use(logger('dev'));    
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// required for passport
app.use(session({ secret: 'zxcv' })); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

app.listen(8000);
module.exports = app;
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var passport = require('passport');
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index.ejs', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.get('/signup', function(req, res) {

        // render the page and pass in any flash data if it exists
        res.render('signup.ejs');
    });

 // process the signup form
 console.log("entering signup");
 router.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {

        successRedirect : '/profile', // redirect to the secure profile section
        failureRedirect : '/signup', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
        failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
    }));    
router.get('/profile', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    console.log("going to profile page.................................................................");
        res.render('profile.ejs', {
            user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
    });


function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on 
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/');
}


module.exports = router;
```

**signup.ejs**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Node Authentication</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- load bootstrap css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"> <!-- load fontawesome -->
    <style>
        body        { padding-top:80px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">

    <h1><span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Signup</h1>


    <% if (message.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger"><%= message %></div>
    <% } %>

    <!-- LOGIN FORM -->
    <form action="/signup" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Signup</button>
    </form>

    <hr>    
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**passport.js** (at below link:)
https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Any help would really help me in completing this tutorial.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: plz solve my problem too.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71398223/ejs-file-is-not-rendering-properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, digged out the fault...... was a very simple and basic error.Happy i did not waste other's time...
**error**: i was not passing the variable into the template while rendering.

**codeChange**:
in **index.js** for the **/signup** path
`res.render('signup.ejs');` changes to `res.render('signup.ejs',{message:'errorMessage'});`